# Remove background style in all html tags using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex, stylesheet

How can I remove all `background="..."` in all HTML tags? I understood that it's not a good idea to try parsing HTML with regexes, but I don't know any over way. (tried regex `"background([\s\S]*?)(;|\")"` - doesn't work).
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By simple script you can use this code,

```
    <script>
    var allElements = document.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++)
    {
        var currElement = allElements[i];
        if (currElement.hasAttribute("background"))
        {
            currElement.removeAttribute("background");
        }
    }
    </script>


and to solve your mentioned issue,
use this,

use this to solve this issue,
`<script>
        function removeBackground(cElement) {
            var allElements = cElement.childNodes;
            if (allElements.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
                    var currElement = allElements[i];
                    if (currElement.childNodes.length > 0) {
                        removeBackground(currElement);
                    }
                    if (currElement.hasAttribute("background")) {
                        currElement.removeAttribute("background");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     removeBackground(document);
    </script>`
```

Comment: `document.childNodes` seems to be faster than `document.querySelectorAll(*);` http://jsperf.com/childnodes-vs-queryselectorall

Comment: There is a little problem than it encounters something like:
<p><span style="background="...">text</span></p>

Comment: Yes, because `document.childNodes` is a property stub while `document.querySelectorAll(*);` is a function stub that give results after execution, Thats why property stub is always faster then others,

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('*').removeAttr('background');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body background="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png">

<h1>Hello world!</h1>
<p>The background attribute is not supported HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can use jquery to remove all background property like,

```
$('*').removeAttr("background");
```

Comment: You did read your snippet, right? "background" isn't supported in html5

Comment: @jbutler but if you read the question, it seems that's what the OP wants to remove

Comment: @Kaiido: However, there is a 'background' in css as well. There is no reference to *this* background or the css background in the question, so (presently) it could be either.

Comment: @jbutler well yes there is : `How can I remove all background="..." in all HTML tags?` if it was css, it would have been `background:...` or `[element.style.]background="..."`but that would have been in js not in `HTML tags`

Comment: "background=.." could be only on the body, right ? (in case of attribute)

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can use a simple selector for that:

`$("*").css('background', 'transparent');`

background attribute instead of style:

`$("*").removeAttr('background');`

Without jQuery it's a bit more work to do:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i = 0, i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.background = "transparent";
}
```

Raw background attribute:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i = 0, i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].hasAttribute("background")) {
        elements[i].removeAttribute("background");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would prefer to remove background. Adding a transparent value will override main CSS settings.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom sheet to override the background property
like this

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
document.head.appendChild(style);

// Depend on browser implementation
if (style.sheet.insertRule) {
    style.sheet.insertRule("* { background:none !important }", 0);
} 
else if (style.sheet.addRule) {
    style.sheet.addRule("*","background:none !important", 0);
}
```